# Renting movies from iTunes onto iPad. Is it streamed or stored temporaly?

Tags: itunes, ipad

I am going on a flight, and I would like to rent a movie for my iPad for the time being. Will I still be able to watch it on-flight if I "rent" it (hours) before take-off or does renting from iTunes is an streaming thing?

Comment: After reading the faq, I really hope this won't get closed. At least not too soon :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's downloaded not streamed (although you can start watching it before it's completely downloaded. Bear in mind that the clock starts ticking once you start watching, you only have 48hrs to finish it).

Answer (score 0):

rentals are available for iPod classics and other devices without internet connectivity, so i assume it's stored.

Answer (score -1):

So far as I know that data is stored temporarily on your ram. Though I'm not very familiar with the iPad and iTunes system. My guess is you would be fine. But I would propose attempting to "rent" the movie and then shut off communication in the iPad. If you can still use it with out the wireless on, you should be fine.

~TA

Comment: can some one explain to me why i got down voted? I just want to understand so i don't repeat what ever mistake I made.